# Programmatically Setting Text of Validation Control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have following validator control.  How can we set the `color` of `Text` of this control from code behind?

Note: Text of the control is `*` as shown in the code below.

**CODE**

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator"
    Text="*" ControlToValidate="TextBox1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `ForeColor` attribute:

```
 RequiredFieldValidator1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
```

Comment: You just changed your question from CustomValidator to RequiredFieldValidator. And yes I use this code and it works.

Comment: No problem. By the way, I recommend you use SetFocusOnError="true" and  Display="Dynamic" for more user-friendly result.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
Style myStyle = new Style();
s.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;

valEmailRecipients.Style = myStyle;
```

Or simply:

```
valEmailRecipients.Style.ForeColor= System.Drawing.Color.Red;
```

[See here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.style.aspx) for reference and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.style.aspx) as well.

Comment: I am getting error - 'System.Web.UI.CssStyleCollection' does not contain a definition for 'ForeColor'. Also .. Property or indexer 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl.Style' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only

Comment: @Lijo yes, because you changed the Type of control. You had originally posted a very different markup which had a CustomValidator not a RequiredFieldValidator.